# How do I pass specific text to a label depending on which UIButton is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm very new to coding and I'm having trouble passing data to a second view controller. I want to change a label in the second view controller depending on which button is pressed in the first (if you press art the label says "art museum", if you press rollercoaster the label says "theme park")

I have tried putting the override function into the brackets for the button but I got the error "override can only be specified on class members"

**firstacCode**

```
class firstacCode: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func art(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "artSegue", sender: self)
    }


        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let destVC : acCode = segue.destination as! acCode
        destVC.descriptionLabel = "art museum"

    }
```

**acCode**

```
class acCode: UIViewController {

    var descriptionLabel :String = "";

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        descriptionText.text = descriptionLabel

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

This worked for me for one button but I'm not sure how to add another button into the equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome to Stackoverflow. You're already doing the passing of data to the other controller correctly. So your only problem now I guess is how to handle multiple buttons in your `IBAction` function.

**Tip:**
You can actually make this `@IBAction func art(_ sender: Any)` as `@IBAction func art(_ sender: UIButton)`. Instead of `Any`, turn it into `UIButton` to avoid casting.

Assuming you connected multiple buttons into that `art` `IBAction` function, you can catch that specific button object through your `sender` and pass that `sender` to the `sender` parameter of your `prepareForSegue`, or in your case, I just realized that you might have different function for your two buttons, just pass the string to that `sender` parameter.

So your code would be like so:

```
@IBAction func art(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "artSegue", sender: "art museum")
}

@IBAction func rollercoaster(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "artSegue", sender: "theme park")
}
```

and in your `prepareForSegue`, cast the `sender` to `String`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVC : acCode = segue.destination as! acCode
    destVC.descriptionLabel = sender as! String
}
```

Comment: Sure no problem. Take your time learning iOS, and learn how to handle optionals to avoid force unwrapping (ex. sender as! String).

Answer (score 3):

First of all connect your buttons to the art function, from the attribute inspector give tags to the buttons.

**Now your code will be look like this** :

```
@IBAction func art(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: "art museum")
    }
    if sender.tag == 1{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: "Theme Park")
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc : acCode = segue.destination as! acCode
    vc.destVc = sender as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func art(_ sender: Any) {
  sender.tag = 1
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "artSegue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func art2(_ sender: Any) {
  sender.tag = 2
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "art2Segue", sender: self)
}


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if(sender.tag == 1){
       let destVC : acCode = segue.destination as! acCode
       destVC.descriptionLabel = "art museum"
     }

     if(sender.tag == 2){
       let destVC : acCode = segue.destination as! acCode
       destVC.descriptionLabel = "art2 museum"
     }

    }
```